# place product image at bottom of the box

Tags: html, css, image, vertical-alignment

[CODE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEpVbq)

I want image to aligned at bottom of the box. There will be product images which are coming from backend and there is not fix size for it.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120422063108/nickelodeon/images/2/27/Spongebob1.gif" alt="" /></li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120717231330/hulksmash/images/7/78/Image_placeholder.jpg" alt="" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  float: left;
  width: 276px;
  text-align: center;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  height: 276px;
  margin: 5px
}
img {
  vertical-align: bottom
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This css did the trick

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  width: 276px;
  text-align: center;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  height: 276px;
  margin: 5px
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
img {
  vertical-align: bottom
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of doing it.

```
li {
position:relative;
}

img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -100%); 
}
```

Comment: better css for img instead of top: `bottom: 0;transform: translate(-50%, 0);`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `line-height` property to the li that is the same as the li's height and it should do the trick.